# SQL Server Keeps Logging/Writing to 'Setup Bootstrap' folder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I recently got a message from windows that my system was running out of disk space.

After a quick search across the file system, I found out the SQL Server had logged 10GB of info in the  folder  **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Files**

Naturally deleting these alleviated the problem, but a recent check found that it is contintuing to write there at a rate of about 35MB daily. Typically nearly all of this is in a file named **SQLSetupXXX_MachineName_Support.log**.

Is there any way of limiting/stopping this logging?